# Google task queue not in us-west1

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-tasks

My gcloud tools default to us-west1 but when I create a queue and try to use via java and apis, I get this error

```
"Location 'us-west1' is not a valid location. Use ListLocations to list valid locations.",
```

and when I try to list locations like it says with gcloud, I get this

```
Deans-The-Machine dean$ gcloud tasks queues list
QUEUE_NAME        STATE    MAX_NUM_OF_TASKS  MAX_RATE (/sec)  MAX_ATTEMPTS
staging-scrapers  RUNNING  25                2.0              3
```

How do I get the locations list with gcloud command line?

thanks,
Dean

Comment: Use the command `gcloud tasks locations list` to see supported locations. Use `us-east4`. https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/tasks/locations/list

Comment: @JohnHanley That command lists one and 'only' one location for me us-central1 .  Why is there only one location?  That seems odd.  all my servers are running in us-west1 so I wanted to run google cloud tasks there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/about/locations#americas) it seems that Cloud Task is not available in  `us-west1`.

Taking a look at the [Cloud Tasks overview](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/dual-overview) you will see that Cloud Tasks requires an App Engine app to be able to host the queues. If you take a look at the currently available regions for [GAE](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/locations), you will see that the region `us-westt` is not listed, therefore, you cannot host the Cloud Tasks queues in that specific region.

I found this [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/150847681) asking for add `us-west1` in the available Regions for App Engine

Answer (score 1):

The cloud tasks can be created where the App Engine is deployed.

To access the Cloud Tasks service using Cloud Tasks API , you must have a project that contains an App Engine app that hosts the Cloud Tasks queues that you create. This app is located in a specific region which serves as the LOCATION_ID parameter for your Cloud Tasks requests, so make a note of it.

As per the [location](https://cloud.google.com/about/locations#locations), Google App Engine is not available in **us-west1**

Comment: hmm, I never deployed a 'google app engine'. we only use cloud run.

Comment: Cloud run and cloud function also creates app engine service account.     The default location is us-central1